# Accessing localStorage from different Browsers

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to access a localStorage key-value pairs from **different Browsers on the same Machine**?
Or has every Browser it's own, specific localStorage? So that only key-values can be accessed which have been set by using that specific Browser.

Comment: No, you can't access local storage of one browser into another browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Each browser has its own localStorage